# Pass variable from broad cast receiver to another function and get result

Tags: java, android

i have a broadcast receiver class which receive the message. i store message and no.in different variables.
and print in toast in front of user .
problem is that i want pass message string in another function  and when i run application the i want ouput result from second function.

my code is

```
package com.example.broadcastreceiver;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


 public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

// Get the object of SmsManager
final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    try {

        if (bundle != null) {

            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

            SmsMessage currentMessage =  SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();


                System.out.println(phoneNumber);
                System.out.println(message);

  Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + message);

           int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "senderNum: "+ senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
                toast.show();

            } // end for loop
          } // bundle is null

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

    }
}


 }
```

my activity class is-

```
package com.example.broadcastreceiver;

import com.androidexample.broadcastreceiver.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;


public class BroadcastNewSms extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.androidexample_broadcast_newsms);
}
}
```

and my second function is here i want pass the message and get the output

```
    String type="CEXAD";
    String caseno="139";
    String year="2013"; 
    String url = "http://"url"?type=" + type + "&num=" + caseno + "&year=" + year;

   public  void print(String type,String caseno,String year,String url) throws IOException{

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(20*1000).get(); 
  Element pending = doc.select("table td:eq(0)").first();
  Element nextDate = doc.select("table td:eq(0)").get(10);
  Element date = doc.select("table td:eq(1)").last();
  int nex=doc.select("table td:eq(0)").size();
```

}

Comment: you asked this question before, did you test those ways that i told?

Comment: So, on the receiver you get the number and message and show it on a Toast and do nothing more with it? You need to store it or pass it along, it won't store itself magically. Write to a DB, to plain text, send it to a server...

Comment: sorry sir but i want to build a app that recive message.message string are like this abxz,139,2013 or xyz3,133,2012 ,i want retrive these string from message string in different variable.and then i pass these variable in the second method that i post .when these variable pass in second method ,give some output.so in android i could not do this.please help me .thanku

Comment: in short i have a url like this String url = "http://"url"?type=" + type + "&num=" + caseno + "&year=" + year; it having 3 parameter type,caseno,year.from message i retrive these value and pass in url that excute and give some result.i want result